# Django admin gives a suspiciouserror when trying to upload an image with imagefield

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I know this is a question asked several times but it seems that this one is a weird issue.

I set settings.py's `MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/siteowner/proj/proj/static/product_photos/'`
and then I created a `photo = models.ImageField("logo", upload_to="", blank=True, null=True)` model attribute.

Of course I've created the right path (the one specified in `MEDIA_ROOT`) and I gave it `chmod 775`.

Despite this when I try to submit the data I always get:

```
SuspiciousOperation at /admin/catalogo/catalog/add/
Attempted access to './image.jpg' denied.
```

As you may see I'm not prepending any slash to upload_to (that seems to be the most common error for this kind of model field).

I'm running django with mod_wsgi in a virtualenv (because I'm on ubuntu 10.04 using py2.7) if this might help (everything is working fine btw, django works as expected).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

'upload_to' can't be blank as far as I know. I would set the MEDIA_ROOT to:

'/home/siteowner/proj/proj/static/'

and then specify 'product_photos' as the upload_to property.

Comment: Also cannot use a relative path as current working directory of Apache process could be anything.